# Django query filter on count in one to many relation

Tags: python, database, django

I have the following models:

```
class Donation(models.Model):
    donation_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    donor_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Charge(models.Model):
    donation = models.ForeignKey(Donation)
    error = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And I have a complex query that should do one of the following:

> Get all donations or all donations which has at least one failed charge.

I came up with the following solution:

```
# get all donations with charge prefetched
all_donations = Donation.objects.all().prefetch_related('charge_set')

# sometimes filter for failed ones
if need_failed_charges:
  all_donations = all_donations.annotate(count=Count('charge')) \
            .filter(charge__error__isnull=False, count__gt=0)
```

Here I use the `count` to track the number of charges I have per donation, I filter them afterward to check if I have at least one.

I think there is a better way to express this, but as I'm still new to the django world I cannot see it.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It's easier to answer this kind of question if you give us more code. I would have preferred the question to contain (possibly cut-down) code for your models, not just a summary description of the models.
2. The comment for the `error` field says "can be null/blank" but your code only tests for NULL, not for blank. If the comment is correct, then your code is buggy; conversely, if the code is correct, then the comment is wrong.
3. The question says, "I filter them afterward to check if I have more than one" but the code says, `count__gt=0`, so it is actually filtering for more than *zero* failed charges. If the text of question is right then the code is buggy.
4. There's no need for the count annotation — if you add a filter on a one-to-many relation then you only get results where there is at least one record that matches the filter. (In SQL terms, Django's filters on one-to-many relations are implemented as *inner* joins.)

   So all that's needed is:

   ```
   # Donations with at least one failed charge.
   Donation.objects.filter(charge__error__isnull=False)
   ```

   You can check this by looking at the SQL that is generated by Django's ORM:

   ```
   >>> print(Donation.objects.filter(charge__error__isnull=False).query)
   SELECT "myapp_donation"."id" FROM "myapp_donation"
     INNER JOIN "myapp_charge"
     ON ( "myapp_donation"."id" = "myapp_charge"."donation_id" )
     WHERE "myapp_charge"."error" IS NOT NULL
   ```

   (The count annotation would, however, be necessary if the requirement were to select donations with *more than one* failed charge, as stated in the question.)